# Adding image into SQL database using ASP.Net Core with React

Tags: c#, sql-server, reactjs, .net-core, image-uploading

So I've been scouring the web for a solution and have tried different implementations but am still unable to save an image into my sql database.

Thank you in advance ... I know there are a lot of resources but I still could not find how to do it.

Currently, our sql type for the image is: varbinary(max) but I have also tried Image type with no success.

Front-end in React I have (It's wrapped in a submit function):

```
// Upload user's signature
url = `api/users/uploadsignature?id=${id}`
let formData = new FormData();

formData.append('signature', this.state.signature, this.state.signature.name);

response = await fetch(url, {
   method: 'POST',
   body: formData,
});
```

This is in the form section:

```
<div className="form-group">
  <label htmlFor="roleSelect">Upload Signature:</label>
  <input
    style={{ display: 'none'}}
    id="signature"
    name="signature"
    type="file"
    className="form-control"
    onChange={this.signatureOnChange}
    ref={fileInput => this.fileInput = fileInput}
  />
  <button type="button" className="btn btn-secondary" onClick={() => this.fileInput.click()}>Pick Image</button>
</div>
```

Back-end Asp.Net Core:

```
[HttpPost("[action]")]
public IActionResult UploadSignature(int id)
{
    var files = HttpContext.Request.Form.Files;
    try { 
        String query = $"UPDATE userAcct set signature='{files[0]}' WHERE userAcct.id={id}";
        String sql = @query;

        dt = sqlConnection.Connection(sql);

        return Ok();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return BadRequest(new { Error = e });
    }
}
```

The sqlConnection function is:

```
public DataTable Connection(String sql)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
    da.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand(sql, con);   

    da.Fill(dt);

    return dt;
}
```

Comment: Can you determine which layer is failing? It looks like it will definitely fail at the back end as an `HttpPostedFile` instance is not something you can directly concatenate into a sql query. Convert the file to bytes and use a `SqlParameter` to get it into the `SqlCommand`.

Comment: You are right, I am getting an error in my DataTable Connection Function in da.SelectCommand. I get the error 
"System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Implicit conversion from data type varchar to varbinary(max) is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query."